# How to include recommender system file (.py) and use the result inside a flutter app

Tags: python, flutter, recommendation-engine

I built a content-based recommender system using python and I want to include it inside my flutter app
( input from flutter app -> passes by the recommender system -> result-> show result inside the flutter app).
is it possible to do so if yes any steps or guidelines would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to build a REST or GraphQL API for the recommender system. You can host this on a server or cloud provider. Then your flutter app can access it by making HTTP requests to the API.